# Change the first character in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to make a for to loop in my array and change the first letter if it was a specific letter, the problem is the loop only work for the first array element.

so if the array was `A123, A345, A567` It will change only `A123 To L123`

here is my code

```
$("#at").click(function() {
   var str= $("#field").val();
   var res = str.split(" ");

    var index =0;
    for (index= 0; index<res.length; index++) {


        if (res[index].substring(0,1) =='A') { 
       res[index] = res[index].substring(1);
       res[index] = "L" + res[index]; 

}

  }

 $("#field").val(res);
```

I am still a newbie in JQuery so if there is a better way to make this, please help

Comment: `res[index].substring(0,1) =='A'`  this is incorrect . It should be res[index].index('A') =='0'

Comment: If you have already defined `index`, you don't have to set the value again. `for (index; index < res.length; index++) {`

Comment: @TusharRaj Could you please explain?

Comment: @TusharRaj could you explain why `res[index].substring(0,1) =='A'` is wrong? Looks perfectly good to me. It checks that the first character is an `A`.

Comment: @AndreasFurster i do not think it makes a difference, i set the value again for the var in the for.

Comment: @George i need to change all the elements, but it only do the first one.

Comment: @BaderHAlRayyes I read backwards, apologies.

Comment: As you can see in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koo2vrgz/), the code works as expected for `str = "A123, A345, A567"`. This suggests that the string you read in from `#field` isn't what you think it is. Check what your `str` variable actually is, whether it has spaces in it like you expect it to, and by extension how many elements the `res` array has – you will likely see the problem.

Comment: @BaderHAlRayyes No it won't make any difference. But why want you to set the variable twice?

Comment: @Shai
When i use split the statement it goes from AAA AAA AAA TO AAA, AAA, AAA, I already can add a character to each word, but i can't modify all of them.

Comment: @Juhana, lets say i add L to all words then i want to replace it with E , it only replace the first L. thats the problem

Comment: yet another way do it with [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) like `"A123, A345, A567".replace(/\bA/g,'L')`

Comment: @Juhana It worked, but try to change L manually in the words, put A , it will change the first element.

Comment: Thanks @Juhana and everyone for trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `res` array is correctly being set to `["L123,", "L345,", "L567"]`.

When you then try to output this, using `$("#field").val(res)`, you are setting `#field`'s value to an array, which has unpredictable results (and may differ cross-browser). Values should be strings.

Try instead for your last line:

```
$("#field").val(res.join(" "));
```

which will join the array back into a string before displaying it.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koo2vrgz/2/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked, could you please explain why there is no , when i press the buttons ?

Comment: How do you mean? You're splitting the string by `(space)`, and joining it together by `(space)` at the end, so the commas never disappear (they are part of each element array – `A123,`, for example). It would, however, be more readable/sensible to split and join by `, ` (comma space) if you know the string will always have `, ` as its separator.